# Execution of ruby OR condition on an array

Tags: ruby

In irb

```
[[]] | [3]
```

produces

```
[[], 3]
```

I am having some difficulty understanding it. How is the OR operator working here ?

Comment: There is no OR operator working here at all.  See the documentation for [Array#| here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is the **logical OR operator** you might be thinking of.

`|` with arrays performs a **set union operation** on the arrays and gives you an array that has all the unique elements of both arrays. More details at [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

Answer (score 3):

According to  [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C),

> Set Union — Returns a new array by joining ary with other_ary,
>   excluding any duplicates and preserving the order from the original
>   array.

```
[1,2,3] | [4,5,6] # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1,2,3] | [4,1,2] # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Its not a simple join, all duplicates are lost, for e.g `[1,1] | [1,1]  => [1]`